# Проблема с NGINX (deploy)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, развертывание

**Описание:**
Разворачиваю приложения на боевом сервере. 
Домен приобритён, DNS ссылается на сервер.

**Проблема:**
Если в браузере перехожу на сайт *http://mysite.com* (например), то получаю стандартную страницу приветствия NGINX, НО если указываю *http://mysite.com/admin/* или *http://mysite.com/api/* или вообще *http://mysite.com/?zz=xx* и т.п., то возвращаются страницы приложения и статика подтягивается.

**ВОПРОС:**
Что нужно сделать (куда копать), чтобы решить проблему? В логах ошибок нет, но при переходе на главную в nginx.access.log пишется информация, а при переходе на `/api/` (и т.п.) в mysite.access.log .

**Конфигурация nginx конфига приложения:**

```
upstream django {
#    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

#    root /home/user/projects/frontend/mysite-frontend/.nuxt;
#    index index.html index.htm index.js;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

    # To frontend
    location / {
    #    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        uwsgi_pass django;
    }

    # To backend
    location /admin/ {
        include proxy_params;
    }

    # To backend
    location /api/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    # To static dir
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/projects/backend/;
    }

    # To media dir
    location /media/ {
        root /home/user/projects/backend/;
    }
}
```

**Статус Gunicorn:**

```
> sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-08-13 06:57:57 UTC; 5s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 90858 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4557)
     Memory: 114.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─90858 /home/user/projects/backend/mysite-env/bin/python /home/user/projects/backend/...
             ├─90862 /home/user/projects/backend/mysite-env/bin/python /home/user/projects/backend/...
             ├─90863 /home/user/projects/backend/mysite-env/bin/python /home/user/projects/backend/...
             └─90864 /home/user/projects/backend/mysite-env/bin/python /home/user/projects/backend/...>

Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user gunicorn[90858]: [2020-08-13 06:57:57 +0000] [90858] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user gunicorn[90858]: [2020-08-13 06:57:57 +0000] [90858] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (9085>
Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user gunicorn[90858]: [2020-08-13 06:57:57 +0000] [90858] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user gunicorn[90862]: [2020-08-13 06:57:57 +0000] [90862] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90862
Aug 13 06:57:57 srv-user gunicorn[90863]: [2020-08-13 06:57:57 +0000] [90863] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90863
Aug 13 06:57:58 srv-user gunicorn[90864]: [2020-08-13 06:57:58 +0000] [90864] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90864
```

**Используемые технологии:**
ОС: Ubuntu Server 20.04 
NGINX: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) 
Backend APP: Django (DRF) + Gunicorn

P.S.
Активно мониторю вопрос.
При необходимости предоставлю дополнительные данные.
*http://mysite.com* - не оригинальный домен, заменил на такой в вопросе в целях безопасности.

Comment: Браузерный Кэш пробовали чистить? Данный код сам по себе не может вызывать таких эффектов

Comment: @Alexey Ten, Да и в режиме инкогнито запускал, результат не изменился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас сохранён стандартный конфиг nginx, который устанавливается при скачивании nginx. Необходимо перейти по пути /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ и удалить там конфиг, который называется default.

Конфиг который использую я для django при разворачивании боевых серверов (пример):

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/server/deployment/uwsgi/uwsgi_nginx.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 8000 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl http2;

    #ssl
    ssl_certificate /home/server/deployment/ssl/my_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/server/deployment/ssl/my_domain.key;

    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name my_domain;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /home/server/backend/my_site/uploads;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/server/deployment/uwsgi/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Файл uwsgi_params:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

ssl можно убрать

Для gunicorn можно попробовать изменить конфиг так (не уверен, что будет работать):

```
upstream django {
    # Лучше указывать полный абсолютный путь а не относительный
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server unix:/..;
}

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111748/discussion-on-answer-by-inventor---nginx-deploy).